# How to account for two covariates in differential gene expression of single cell RNA seq data?

Tags: r, seurat

I have human data from different ages and gender. After using integration with `seurat`, how would I best control for these confounding factors during differential gene expression analysis. I see the option of latent.vars in `FindMarkers` function. Can I give `latent.vars = c("Age", "gender")` to account for both together? or can I only use one at a time?

Is there alternative package to do the test better?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question. Unfortunately, this is the wrong place to ask. Try biostars.org

Answer (score 1):

You can use that argument, but what it means is that you are shifting to a glm based model, and not the default wilcoxon test. you can also see it in the help page (`?FindMarkers`) :

```
latent.vars: Variables to test, used only when ‘test.use’ is one of
          'LR', 'negbinom', 'poisson', or 'MAST'
```

You can see how the glm is called in [the source code](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/blob/master/R/differential_expression.R), under GLMDETest. Basically these two covariates are included in the glm to account for their effects on the dependent variable. What is also important is how you treat the covariate age in this case. Would it be categorical or continuous.. this could affect your results.